# Remove specific section of a string

Tags: jquery

I am making use of matching a url from a tab to the window.location, but am using secure routes. How do I remove the a part of a string from a selected character, In my case the char is '?' I want to remove everything from the ? to the end of the string. How can this be done with jquery?

```
document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link').forEach(link => {
        console.log(link);
        if(link.href === window.location.href){
            link.setAttribute('aria-current', 'page')
        }
    })
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of url?

Comment: /sales-report-per-cashier?formToken=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJwYXlsb2FkIjoiXC9zYWxlcy1yZXBvcnQtcGVyLWNhc2hpZXIiLCJleHBpcmVzIjoxNjY4MTY4OTQyfQ.5E99YVZFxdea8vBEppKZAXnyjSpOukWaFocCC3Qwv6x4CmT35O5xA--EOXZjjqU-CuLlVsUtQcEDl_dsMEZsTNuxuHm9TXQd49bPtBpiHode8rZ8QzMrKnAg40HQlWzO8jMjkZ1uj2mzfbWxf6aft0O2-3MPhtF8HVnnvC4Rzhg

Comment: i want to remove everything from the '?' to the end of the url

Answer (score 1):

you can use the split function simply like this

```
let link = link.split('?');
let required_link = link[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link').forEach(link => {
    if(link.pathname === window.location.pathname){
        link.setAttribute('aria-current', 'page')
    }
})
```

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it better,